# is there a simple way to make a pop up box in ASP.NET appear?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I tried using this example: http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/modalpopup/modalpopup.aspx

```
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="MPE" runat="server"
TargetControlID="LinkButton1"
</ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
```

And try using

```
MPE.Show();
```

on the C# side but I keep getting an error message: 
"The name 'MPE' does not exist in the current context" I really don't know why the C# side can't see the asp side.

I mean the popup doesn't have to use ajax but that's what I was currently trying at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modal popup extender needs a control to extend:

```
<!-- modal popup target - hidden -->
<asp:Button ID="btnModalTarget" runat="server" style="display:none;" />

<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="PopupExtender1" runat="server"
    BehaviorID="ModalPopupBehavior1"
    TargetControlID="btnModalTarget"
    PopupControlID="Panel1">     
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>   
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
    <!-- popup contents -->
</asp:Panel>

<asp:LinkButton ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Open" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PopupExtender1.Show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The control is extended to a control which is a button? Is it possible to just have the pop up appear when the page loads instead of clicking on a button?

Comment: My example sets the extender to an invisible target (because it's required), but the LinkButton is the control that actually displays the dialog. Now you're looking to display the dialog on page load instead?